# Single application-wide process to be accessed by child processes

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I'm writing an Elixir application where some of the processes that access the database will be generating unique identifiers for records that get inserted.

I'm using the [CUID library](https://github.com/duailibe/cuid/blob/master/lib/cuid.ex) which will let me generate an id in the following way:

```
{:ok, pid} = Cuid.start_link
Cuid.generate(pid)  # => ch72gsb320000udocl363eofy
```

Here is how my app is setup

- There is a phoenix controller which handles a request
- This controller calls out to my custom Repo.insert command which is currently synchronous
- Repo.insert calls Cuid.start_link and Cuid.generate every time

Creating a new Cuid process each time feels wrong to me, especially considering that the Cuid lib maintains a counter in its state.

How can different processes within my application send `Cuid.generate` to the same process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start it up as a supervised and registered worker in your application:

```
defmodule MyApp do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(MyApp.Endpoint, []),
      # Start the Ecto repository
      worker(MyApp.Repo, []),
      worker(Cuid, [], [name: :cuid])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyApp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  ...
end
```

And then use it in your application like:

```
cuid = Cuid.generate(:cuid)
```

Comment: Thanks, I opted for this approach. I'm curious why the :cuid alias is available within a Phoenix request. What is the scope of such an alias? Is it accessible to MyApp and everything underneath its supervision tree?

Comment: When you register a process it is globally accessible by that alias.  Thus, you want to be careful when using this pattern, as you do not want to create a bottleneck in your app.  It should only be used for a truly singleton situation.  You can substitute the alias most places where you would use a PID, such as the `GenServer.call` and `GenServer.cast` functions.  Also the `Process.whereis` function, etc.  The global registry has some other downsides in distributed applications and if you need to use it in a truly distributed app you may consider https://github.com/uwiger/gproc in lieu of it.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. Does this mean if I had an umbrella app which supervised apps A and B, the process aliases would be shared between A and B?

Comment: It depends on how you build and deploy your application (see [EXRM](https://github.com/bitwalker/exrm)).  If you add an additional app to the umbrella that includes and starts apps A and B, then yes.  However, you could also choose to build A and B as separate apps and deploy them to different servers.  Sometimes you may want the convenience of a single project in `development`, but to deploy the apps differently.  Mix handles the concern of starting the apps within the umbrella in `development`, but will not be present in the `prod` build.

Answer (score 2):

You can *register* your process:

```
Process.register(pid, :cuid_process)
```

This way it becomes available to all processes in the entire system. Usually you can use the atom under which process is registered in all places that take regular pid, so you can try:

```
Cuid.generate(:cuid_process)
```